# Wait for threads to finish before running them again

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, python-multithreading

I am making a program that controls 2 motors through a raspberry Pi. I am running python code and I am wondering how to achieve the following :

- Run motor1
- Run motor2 simultaneously
- Wait for both motors to finish
- Run motor1
- Run motor2 simultaneously
- etc.

  What I have done so far is creating a Thread and using a queue.

  ```
  class Stepper(Thread):

      def __init__(self, stepper):
          Thread.__init__(self)
          self.stepper = stepper    
          self.q = Queue(maxsize=0)

      def setPosition(self, pos):
          self.q.put(pos)

      def run(self):
          while not self.q.empty():
              item = self.q.get()
              // run motor and do some stuff 

  thread_1 = Stepper(myStepper1)
  thread_2 = Stepper(myStepper2)
  thread_1.start()
  thread_2.start()

  loop = 10
  while(loop):
      thread_1.setPosition(10)
      thread_2.setPosition(30)
      # I want to wait here
      thread_1.setPosition(10)
      thread_2.setPosition(30)
      loop = loop - 1

      thread_1.join()
      thread_2.join()
  ```

Both thread_1 and thread_2 won't finish at the same time depending of the numbers of steps the motor need to process. 
I have tried to use the Lock() functionality but I am not sure how to correctly implement it. I also thought about re-creating the Threads but not sure if this is the correct solution.

Comment: Please fix your indents it's disturbance when other reads your code.

Comment: Where do you remove Items from self.q and where do you initialize it like q = Queue()

Comment: Yes, the queue is initialised in the def __init__ like so  : self.q = Queue(maxsize=0) (each thread has its own queue) ; I also do a  item = self.q.get() in my run() method, I will update my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Semaphore) actually:

```
from threading import Semaphore

class Stepper(Thread):

    def __init__(self, stepper, semaphore):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stepper = stepper
        self.semaphore = semaphore

    def setPosition(self, pos):
        self.q.put(pos)

    def run(self):
        while not self.q.empty():
            try:
                # run motor and do some stuff
            finally:
                self.semaphore.release()  # release semaphore when finished one cycle

semaphore = Semaphore(2)
thread_1 = Stepper(myStepper1, semaphore)
thread_2 = Stepper(myStepper2, semaphore)
thread_1.start()
thread_2.start()

loop = 10
for i in range(loop):
    semaphore.acquire()
    semaphore.acquire()
    thread_1.setPosition(10)
    thread_2.setPosition(30)
    semaphore.acquire()
    semaphore.acquire()  # wait until the 2 threads both released the semaphore
    thread_1.setPosition(10)
    thread_2.setPosition(30)
```

Comment: Some try finallys would suit here perfectly, in order to make sure the lock is released.

Comment: @rocksteady true.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying with semaphore, but I am running into problems : 
 - It seems that when I start() the thread, because the queue is empty, the thread stops, and never run again. (if I call self.run() in the setPosition() for example, the threads won't run simultaneously anymore) 
 - I can add a while(True) in the run method, but then the thread will never stops and program will never ends.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the thread's `join` method like so:

```
thread_1.join() # Wait for thread_1 to finish
thread_2.join() # Same for thread_2
```

As per the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join:

> A thread can be `join()`ed many times.

To run threads repeatedly, you will need to reinitialize the `Thread` object after each run.

Comment: I am not sure how to "reinitialize the Thread object after each run". Is that just a thread_1 = Stepper(myStepper1) in my while(loop) ? I am not sure if this is the best solution, but again I am new in python code.